# When using WinTask to web scrape, is there a way so that it executes but does not open the browser?

Tags: windows, web, web-scraping, task, scraper

I just started using WinTask and I need to do some web scraping with it. Something that would be very useful would be not having the browser open everytime it runs. I know when creating a custom scraper in other languages, such as Java, this can be done but I haven't been able to find anything on whether this program can.

I've been searching online and there is very little about this tool and the WinTask tech support never answered.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

WinTask needs an opened browser, it works at the user interface level.